# What is Windows 8 loader?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I bought a new laptop and it contained the original Windows 8. When I tried to install Linux, something happened and I lost the Windows partition as well as the recovery partition. I tried installing Windows 8 Professional version from a CD, but my BIOS rejected to install from it.

Finally I bought a Windows 8 CD which said it was a loader. It installed perfectly, and now I am working with it. My question is what is Windows 8 loader, and how do I upgrade to Windows 8 Professional version? (I have a genuine key)

Answer (score 0):

Is the CD that you have bought genuine? Because "Window 8 Loader" is actually the *cracking tool* used to active non-genuine Windows copies.

**Don't worry though!**
If you have a key, just go to `Control Panel` and search for `activate windows`. Follow the on-screen instructions to install your genuine key.

Comment: The key I have is for windows 8 proffesional version, and when i follow the instructions as you said, it says version does not match.

Comment: Ok, I get it. You probably have installed other version of windows (ex. Home premium). I remember that in windows **7** there was a feature called **Windows anytime upgrade**, I will check if there is such thing for Windows 8.

Comment: Alright. I wasn't able to find much infomation about this because every search with "Windows 8 Upgrade editions" gives me upgrade from Windows 7, Vista, etc. However, from the general lack of info I *think* it's only possible by burning a new disk with Windows 8 Pro version, and choosing the "Upgrade" option at the installation.

Comment: From where can I download a windows 8 trial version for free? bdw thanx a lot for trying to help me out. :)

Comment: Wait! [try this first](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6673-add-features-windows-8-a.html).

Comment: @DesirePRG - Why do you want a Windows 8 trial .iso you have an actual license.

Comment: @Ramhound - Because he will be able to activate the trail later, after installation. But there's not need for it, check out my previous comment

Comment: thanx matan129. I'll try that

Comment: @matan129 - There are only two editions of Windows 8.  `Windows 8` and `Windows 8 Professioanl` the `Windows Anytime Upgrade` feature was more or less retired. although its stil possible to upgrade a `Windows 8` license to a `Windows 8 Professional` license within Windows ( the process is pretty much exactly the same as it was with `Anytime Time Upgrade`.  Still don't understand the purpose of the trial media if they already have a working installation media.

Comment: I've proposed the installation media before I noticed that there is an option of upgrading version in Windows 8, like in Windows 7. Of course that the second option is better. This is why I wrote "Wait! [Try this first](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6673-add-features-windows-8-a.html).